Chromium won't open without --no-sandbox
Today I installed chromium version 131.0.6778.204 and noticed that when loading through the terminal this comes out:
[15221:15221:1227/074051.331134:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(101)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported
Image
I would be grateful if someone could help me.
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 Jammy Jellyfish
Architecture: arm64

You should not run chromium as root at all.

When running without root, a completely different error occurs

Running a web browser as root is a serious security risk, using the --no-sandbox-option would make it even worse. Please edit your question and add the entire error message you get when trying to run chromium as a non-root user. No screenshots please, copy the terminal output and paste it into your question.

"Chromium won't open without --no-sandbox" --using root-- is a key element of the title. Running anything as root is a security risk. "When running without root, a completely different error occurs "  and your answer to that is to run it as root?? I would suggest to fix that error ....
